# Dotnetnuke Module usage by role

Tags: dotnetnuke

I would like to see for each portal how many times a particular module was viewed, that is number 
of views for a module based on role.

Can we generate this using SQL Query.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find usage first you must have site logs on. Second there is no exact logging per-module. Because one Tab may have more than one module on it. However we can imagine if page is viewed - all modules on that page are viewed. I think following query is going to give you count by module

```
    SELECT  R.PortalID,
        TM.ModuleID,
        R.RoleName,
        COUNT(1) TotalViews
FROM    Roles R WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN dbo.UserRoles UR WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON R.RoleID = UR.RoleID
        INNER JOIN dbo.SiteLog sl WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON sl.UserId = ur.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.TabModules tm WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON tm.TabID = sl.TabId
GROUP BY R.PortalID,
        TM.ModuleID,
        R.RoleName
```

However result will not be that useful because one user may belongs to more than one role. Second I have ignored join with ModulePermissions because most modules do use inherit view permissions.

Comment: Thank you, but we dont have the Site log turned on. The other alternative i had thought is to read TabID from IIS logs that belong to specific module, Thank you for your pointer though.